# Rust not optimizing out C wrappers for C++ functions with LTO

Tags: c++, c, rust, linker, clang

In trying to call a C++ function from Rust by first wrapping it in a C function and then calling the latter via Rust's FFI, I've noticed that rustc does not optimize away the C function call even when LTO is enabled. For example, I have the following files:

```
// foo_cc.h - just a dummy C++ function I want to call from Rust

#pragma once

namespace foo  
{
  __attribute__((noinline))
  void do_something()
  { asm("nop"); }

}
```

```
/* foo_c.h - wrapper header for foo_cc.h */

#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void foo_do_something();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

```
/* foo_c.cc - wrapper source file for foo_cc.h */

#include "foo_c.h"
#include "foo_cc.h"

void foo_do_something()
{ foo::do_something(); }
```

```
// foo.rs - main Rust file calling `foo_do_something`

#[link(name="foo_c")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn foo_do_something();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { foo_do_something(); }
}
```

I build on amd64 with LTO and optimization enabled like this:

```
clang++ -flto=thin -O3 -c foo_c.cc -o foo_c.o
ar rcs libfoo_c.a foo_c.o
rustc -C linker-plugin-lto -C opt-level=3 -Clinker=clang -Clink-arg=-fuse-ld=lld foo.rs -L . -o foo
```

Now when I run `foo` through `objdump`, I see that the main function first performs a jump to `foo_do_something` which in turn does nothing but to jump to `_ZN3foo12do_somethingEv`. If I were to call `foo_do_something` from another C file, LTO would optimize away this intermediate jump, yet `rustc` doesn't. Is there a technical reason for this? Or am I missing some command line option etc.?

Comment: According to [the LTO page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/linker-plugin-lto.html#toolchain-compatibility), cross-lang LTO requires that the LLVM versions of the compiler specifically match. Have you checked that that's the case for you? The other steps you show here seem to match so IDK, maybe look for a cross-lang LTO demo on the internets and see if it works on your setup? The LTO page sadly does not seem to provide such a demo project (maybe something to open an issue for)

Comment: @Masklinn: That's a good point, rustc says it's using llvm 12.0.1, clang reports 12.0.0. Is that already a "mismatch"?

Comment: I fear I've no idea, the LTO page only seems to list major versions so I would hope not but I really have no idea what the stability guarantees of LLVM bitcode are.

Comment: @Masklinn I just tried this with another Rust toolchain that uses llvm 12.0.0 and no luck yet. So there seems to be another issue.

Comment: Works fine fore me on Ubuntu 20.04 + rustc 1.53.0 + clang 12.0.1:
```000000000003e100 <_ZN3foo4main17h01c678bd20b20e11E>:
   3e100:       e9 9b 00 00 00          jmpq   3e1a0 <_ZN3foo12do_somethingEv>
```

Comment: @HHK That's weird, I'll try again with clang 12.0.1.

Comment: @HHK I've just come back to this, it does work with rustc and clang both using llvm 12.0.1 but not with both using 12.0.0, maybe something was fixed in that version. You can post that as an answer if you want.

Comment: @Peter I feel like we did not really get to the bottom of this so it might be better to just leave it unanswered.